# C++ safe alternative to dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, casting

In what scenarios can be `reinterpret_cast` used to cast from a base pointer that's actually a derived instance pointer? (via polymorphism).

Static casts do not work if the inheritance is polymorphic.

I considered this trivial scenario:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void Hello()
    {
        cout<<" A ";
    }
    virtual int GetType() { return 1; }
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    void Hello()
    {
        cout<< " B ";
    }
    void Do()
    {
        cout << " Another method of B";
    }
    int GetType() { return 2;}
};

/// ... sample/test code
A* a1 = new A();
A* b1 = new B();
A* a2;
B* b2;

if (a1->GetType() == 1)
{
    a2 = a1;
    a2->Hello();
}
else
if (a1->GetType() == 2)
{
    b2 = reinterpret_cast<B*>(a1);
    b2->Do();
    b2->Hello();
}
```

Mind the very naive "pseudo type identification method `GetType()` ) I used to decide whether I can convert them or not. Is it downright wrong to use reinterpret_casts at all, for such purposes, of avoid dynamic_casts? (i.e. is it a paranoic design, inherently dangerous and less flexible that can introduce unwanted trouble? Might it be safer and worth the minor performance cost to perform normal dynamic casts? I know that multiple inheritance and/or virtual inheritance will mess up any other cast operation, except for the polymorphic/dynamic one).

Comment: What do you mean -- "Static casts do not work if the inheritance is polymorphic."? `static_cast` is *exactly* what you want here.

Comment: For some reason, MS VC2010 will not allow substituting the reinterpret_cast with a static_cast. Maybe this is a Microsoft specific safety mechanism..

Comment: @teodron: i'm unable to reproduce the compiler bug with msvc 2012 (visual c++ 11.0). also i have never seen that bug. so could you post an example that exhibits that bug?

Comment: @teodron: `static_cast` does not work if you have **virtual inheritance** OR if you cast **across branches**. In those situations, only `dynamic_cast` is available. And that's it.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: What do you mean by "across branches"? If there's no virtual inheritance, you should be able to do that by a sequence of static casts.

Comment: @KerrekSB: By a sequence of `static_cast`, yes, but in a single shot only `dynamic_cast` may.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I used cricular referencing and casting in a base class method, the compiler was not capable of solving that static cast in that situation. In conclusion, my fault for not seeing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use `reinterpret_cast` to downcast safely. But you can use

- `static_cast`, when you know that the dynamic type of the object is (possibly derived from) the one you cast down to, and
- `dynamic_cast`, of reference or pointer, if the statically known class is polymorphic.

In the other direction, for an *upcast* you can (but should not) use a C style cast in order to cast to an inaccessible base. It's specially supported in the standard. I have never found occasion to use it, though.

Comment: I think the word "safely" is superfluous in the first sentence, non? But +1 for the point about inaccessible bases.

Comment: @Kerrek: I wrote "safely" because `reinterpret_cast` can be used to unsafely cast down. The in-practice unsafety comes about because a `reinterpret_cast` does not (in practice) adjust the pointer value. For example, when the base class is non-polymorphic but the derived class is, then with e.g. Visual C++ one typically gets an address adjustment for converting between pointer to base and derived (this has surprised some folks, and some have even demanded proof that it *can* occur!)

Comment: @KerrekSB: Pedantically, you can use `reinterpret_cast` to downcast between two standard-layout classes. But you really, really shouldn't.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: That would still sound like an aliasing violation. The only exception I can see is the one Mike points out about standard layout (which forbids multiple non-empty bases).

Comment: @KerrekSB: Multiple non-virtual bases are allowed; but no more than one class in the heirarchy can have data members, so multiple bases can't affect the layout.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Yeah, thanks, I just checked that in the standard. Interesting point! (And probably even more interesting in the context of unions.)

Answer (score 5):

To just answer your first sentence: never.

The only valid way to *convert* a base pointer to a more-derived pointer statically is with a `static_cast`, and that only works if the base is non-virtual:

```
Base * b = &derived;                       // implicit Derived * => Base *

Derived * p = static_cast<Derived *>(b);   // OK, I know what *b really is
```

A static cast should be thought of as the opposite of an implicit conversion.

A `reinterpret_cast` is just outright wrong. (The only reinterpret-casts that are generally acceptable are to char pointers for the purpose of I/O.)

(When you have a pointer to a *virtual* base, you have no choice but to use a `dynamic_cast`, but that is of course because the base subobject is only determined at runtime in that case.)

Comment: "The only valid way to convert a base pointer to a more-derived pointer is with a static_cast" is wrong. I see the emphasis on *convert*, but if that is meant to point out a special meaning of the word, then it's not founded in the standard or common terminology.

Comment: Good points, but assuming one knows for sure the result of a `dynamic_cast` should be a pointer of the derived class, but the base is virtual, is this the only alternative? (i.e. is using dynamic casts  as expensive as calls to virtual methods and static casting?)

Comment: @teodron: Probably about as expensive as each other, but the only way to be sure is to measure it.

Comment: @teodron: You're probably worrying about the wrong things. If you already have a virtual base and are prepared to deal with the run-time cost of that, the dynamic_cast (should you really require a cast at all!) should not be a problem. "Virtual" means "I'll tell you at runtime", and if that's what you need, you gotta pay for it.

 I'd be more worried about the design that requires the cast in the first place. That seems unnecessary.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, thanks, that's what I _must_ do now :). I fear the premature optimization mirage is the choice of this bad design.

Answer (score 1):

you should avoid doing reinterpret_cast when possible, the main reason to use reinterpret_cast is when you are dealing with legacy code written in C otherwise static_cast and dynamic_cast should be prefered, if your design requires you to use reinterpret_cast you may want to take this as a hint that your design may not be optimal.

static_cast is ok to use for polymorphic types as long as you are sure they will always succeed otherwise you should use dynamic_cast.

Answer (score 0):

Why avoid a `dynamic_cast` in this case? By having to call a virtual member function before doing the cast, you're likely paying more (in terms of performance) than you would by using `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: So, overall, doing dynamic_casts for RTTI is worse than calling a virtual method?

Comment: Compilers typically implement `virtual` member functions via at most a handful of pointer redirects (more, I think, if the inheritance is `virtual` -- like 2 if there is no `virtual` inheritance).  On the other hand, there is no practical way to do a `dyanmic_cast` I am aware of that doesn't end up falling back on the equivalent of a string comparison.  Now, a successful `dyanmic_cast` can sometimes be faster...

Answer (score 0):

Calling a B method function on something that isn't a B is dangerous to do. The question is titled "safe" alternative, and your code is not safe.

Most of the time, using dynamic_cast is bad and a sign of poor design.

There are occasions when it is useful, particularly when working with versioned plugins. You load a plugin and get an object which may or may not support a new feature, and you can dynamically cast the interface (base class) you know it does support to the later version (which has derived from it). If it works, you can use the new feature, if it doesn't you have to disable this functionality or use an older way of doing things.

Sometimes you can use double-dispatch to do this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

The only "safe" alternative to dynamic_cast I know is using the [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). Example ([Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/wAhwRI)):

```cpp
class A;
class B;

class TypeVisitor {
 public:
    virtual void VisitA(A&) = 0;
    virtual void VisitB(B&) = 0;
    virtual ~TypeVisitor() = default;
};

class A
{
public:
    virtual void Hello()
    {
        cout<<" A\n";
    }

    virtual int GetType() { return 1; }

    virtual void Accept(TypeVisitor& visitor) {
        visitor.VisitA(*this);
    }
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    void Hello() override
    {
        cout<< " B\n";
    }

    void Do()
    {
        cout << " Another method of B\n";
    }

    int GetType() override { return 2; }

    void Accept(TypeVisitor& visitor) override {
        visitor.VisitB(*this);
    }
};

class PrintHelloVisitor : public TypeVisitor {
 public:
    virtual void VisitA(A& a) override {
        a.Hello();
    }

    virtual void VisitB(B& b)  override {
        b.Hello();
        b.Do(); // calling also the method that is not virtual
    }

    virtual ~PrintHelloVisitor() = default;
};

int main() {
    PrintHelloVisitor print_visitor;

    unique_ptr<A> a1 = make_unique<A>();
    a1->Accept(print_visitor);

    unique_ptr<A> b1 = make_unique<B>();
    b1->Accept(print_visitor);

    unique_ptr<B> b2 = make_unique<B>();
    b2->Accept(print_visitor);
}
```

Prints:

```
 A
 B
 Another method of B
 B
 Another method of B
```